# F# List.length always return 1?

Tags: list, f#

Why I get the output like below?

```
> List.length [1,2,3];;
val it : int = 1
> List.length [1,2,3,4];;
val it : int = 1
```

I expected to get 3 and 4! Am I using incorrect function call?

Comment: This was answered below, but don't feel bad. This is a really really common mistake :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not about the function - it's about the way you enter the items of the list. You use `,` instead of `;`!

```
> List.length [1,2,3];;
val it : int = 1
> List.length [1;2;3];;
val it : int = 3
```

the reason is that `[1,2,3]` is a **list of tuples** with just one item:

```
> [1,2,3];;
val it : (int * int * int) list = [(1, 2, 3)]
```

see the `(..)` in the output - sadly you can enter tuples with out the `(..)` and many fall for it

If you use `;` instead you get a **list of ints** with 3 elements:

```
> [1;2;3];;
val it : int list = [1; 2; 3]
```

Comment: Why would the optionality of tuple parentheses be a sad thing? No need for that boilerplate :-) Once the list is used for something more meaningful, types will prevent errors like this.

Comment: It's a thing of consistency IMO and it's a thing of readability - when you compare the input `[1,2,3]` to `[(1,2,3)]` (as in the output) - which is more clear? - Also this is a common mistake that happens all the time - especially if you know something like Haskell, Javascript or Python - all of which use `,`...

Comment: Readability is also a function of context. Here I *would* put parentheses. E.g. in function signatures, taking type-annotated tuples, it might be more readable to leave them out (consistently here and there). For new developers `(1, "a") : int * string`, i.e. `,` vs. `*` is also difficult at first. But IMO a language should be rated on what you *can* do (e.g. nice DSLs) before the initial learning curve (given safety is not compromised). As with every other tool, one also needs to learn how to not overdo it (e.g. Scala collection operators). Crippling power because of this would be sad.

Comment: if you like we can discuss this elsewhere but I don't think that the comment section here is a good place

Comment: The rule of thumb to remember is that in F#, the comma is an operator that either creates or destructures tuples. Generic type definitions aside, that's all it does.